# Embox compilation and flashing

Tags: c, linker, operating-system, real-time

I am interested in attempting to compile, package and flash [Embox](https://github.com/embox/embox) to an MCU, from either a Windows or Mac machine (cross-compilation), via JTAG, and I have a number of concerns.

Observe what I *believe* to be the normal way of writing Embox apps and deploying/flashing them to an MCU:

[image]

As you can see, in my *understanding* above:

- Embox source code is compiled (via `make`) into some file (Object file?), `<file>.<ext>`
- At the same time, my app's source code is cross-compiled (somehow) into an Object file (`myapp.o)` that is compatible with Embox
- Some tool combines: (a) the Embox `<file>.<ext>` produced by `make`, (b) `myapp.o` and (c) any other libs I specify. It takes these as inputs and produces a single application image that is ready to be flashed via JTAG

My concerns, also identified in the illustration:

- What is the exact name and file extension of the Embox "artifact" produced by running `make` on Embox source code? Is this artifact different depending on whether you are on Windows or Mac? What tools besides `make` are necessary to produce this artifact?
- What is this magic tool that takes in Object/interim files and produces a single app image? What is the exact name and file extension of this app image?
- What tools do I need to cross-compile `myapp.c` and `myapp.h` into a `myapp.o` that is Embox compatible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm one of the Embox developers, who is responsible for build tools.

Basile [has given](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/283980/179404) a correct overview of the process as a whole:

- the source is compiled into a relocatable `embox.o` with `ld -r`,
- then linked into `embox` ELF binary,
- ... which in turn is additionally transformed into `.bin` and `.srec` that are used for flashing quite often.

Binary artifacts go into `build/base/bin`.

Let me add few details.

First of all, you'll probably won't need to dig into the details of linking your application against Embox. Instead, the proper way is to *integrate* your app into [Mybuild](http://code.google.com/p/embox/wiki/Mybuild) - the Embox build system - and let it handle low-level linkage details for you. So it's worth building vanilla Embox first and see it running on an emulator.

## Building and running Embox for ARM

I would suggest you to start with `arm/qemu` template. This won't fit into your MCU, but if your application doesn't do something unusual, it would be easier to test it on QEMU before porting it to the target MCU. Anyway, this is a good starting point to check that a dev environment is sane and everything builds OK.

Developing on Linux would really make your life easier, like just `sudo apt-get install build-essential` plus few packages and installing a cross-compiler. However, if you're going to develop on Windows, you may find [this guide](http://code.google.com/p/embox/wiki/InstallToolchain) useful. In addition, you'll need to patch `make` to make it work on Windows: [Issue 504](https://github.com/embox/embox/issues/504). And here is [how to](http://code.google.com/p/embox/wiki/SimulationQemu) setup QEMU.

The recommended cross-compiler for ARM is the official [GNU Tools for ARM](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded).

So basically, here are steps to prepare a Linux dev machine for building and running Embox for ARM:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:terry.guo/gcc-arm-embedded
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc-arm-none-eabi u-boot-tools qemu-system
```

Clone the repository:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/embox/embox embox
cd embox
```

Build `arm/qemu`:

```sh
make confload-arm/qemu
make
```

`confload` target initializes a `conf/` directory with a predefined template called `arm/qemu`. `conf/` is where a configuration of the target image (Embox + your app) resides.

Run QEMU. There's a handy wrapper for that, that infers the necessary options from the Embox configuration and runs QEMU properly:

```sh
sudo ./scripts/qemu/auto_qemu
```

If everything goes fine, you'll see something [like that](https://travis-ci.org/embox/embox/jobs/62699078#L5981). Type `help` to list available commands.

## Adding your application as an Embox command

Personally, when trying something new to me I usually "mimic" someone else's approaches to get the first feedback from the application/system. Here, I'd suggest to derive, e.g. an existing [`cat` command](https://github.com/embox/embox/blob/a5fe798c1ca668ea825988bcc1fbdcaa5926475e/src/cmds/fs/cat.c), throw everything away from it, effectively turning it into a Hello world application.

For now, create a directory `hello` in `src/cmds` and add there two files:

### `hello.c` file

```c
/**
 * Plain C Hello World application.
 */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this is a regular C program, that doesn't use any Embox-specific APIs. Let's integrate it into Embox now.

### `Hello.my` file

([refer to `Cat.my`](https://github.com/embox/embox/blob/a5fe798c1ca668ea825988bcc1fbdcaa5926475e/src/cmds/fs/Cat.my)):

```c
package embox.cmd.hello

@AutoCmd
@Cmd(name = "hello",
    help = "<This is what `help hello` will output>",
    man = '''
        <What is shown when running `man hello`>
    ''')
module hello {
    source "hello.c"

    depends embox.compat.libc.all  // for stdio
}
```

Now add the newly defined module into the configuration.

### `conf/mods.config` file

```c
package genconfig

configuration conf {
    ...

    include embox.cmd.hello.hello
}
```

### Build and run

Run `make`. This will compile `hello.c` and link it with Embox appropriately. After that, run it with `sudo ./scripts/qemu/auto_qemu` and type `hello` into the `embox>`prompt.

That's it.

## Regarding your questions

To summarize:

> Embox source code is compiled (via `make`) into some file (Object file?), `<file>.<ext>`
>   At the same time, my app's source code is cross-compiled (somehow) into an Object file (`myapp.o)` that is compatible with Embox

Both your application and Embox itself are compiled together with a regular (cross-)compiler, [defined in `conf/build.conf`](https://github.com/embox/embox/blob/a5fe798c1ca668ea825988bcc1fbdcaa5926475e/templates/arm/qemu/build.conf#L8) through a `CROSS_COMPILE` variable.

> Some tool combines: (a) the Embox `<file>.<ext>` produced by `make`, (b) `myapp.o` and (c) any other libs I specify. It takes these as inputs and produces a single application image that is ready to be flashed via JTAG

These are linked with `ld` as part of the build process.

> What is the exact name and file extension of the Embox "artifact" produced by running `make` on Embox source code? Is this artifact different depending on whether you are on Windows or Mac?

The main build artifacts are `build/base/bin/embox` (ELF) and `build/base/bin/embox.bin` (binary). If I'm not mistaken, these all have the same extension on all build platforms (well, may be there will be `embox.exe` instead of `embox`, but that's unlikely).

> What tools besides `make` are necessary to produce this artifact?

The cross-compiler, essentially. [GNU Tools for ARM embedded processors](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded) is a good choice.

Plus some quirks in case of Windows (see above).

> What is this magic tool that takes in Object/interim files and produces a single app image? What is the exact name and file extension of this app image?

There's no such magic tool. :)

> What tools do I need to cross-compile `myapp.c` and `myapp.h` into a `myapp.o` that is Embox compatible?

This is, again, hidden beneath Mybuild. In a nutshell, it:

- compiles `myapp.c` using the cross-compiler into `myapp.o`
- if the app is defined as a `@AutoCmd` module, it:

  - registers the app in a command registry by storing a pointer to `main` among with some metadata like name
  - strips away the `main` symbol from the object file to prevent conflicts in case of multiple apps
- links `myapp.o` as it were a part of Embox into `embox.o` and then into `embox` ELF

Comment: Care to help integrate your tools into ALT Linux? ;-) (I'm one of its developers by chance)

Comment: Thanks for the kind offer! What exactly do you mean by integrating into ALT Linux? Providing a corresponding package in the repository?

Comment: Yup, so the apt-related part of the above HOWTO might be adapted either.  Still this would make sense if any of you or your users is prone to use ALT of course. :) (we could probably accept the packages into repos proper with no need to add anything)

Comment: @Michael sorry for the late response, I've been on vacation. The problem is that this guide is about building Embox only; the whole Mybuild thing is a build system of Embox and it is a part of Embox at the moment. There is an attempt to separate these projects, but this is still under development. Anyway I would be happy to let you know once we make the tool ready for using with arbitrary projects!

Comment: заранее благодарен :-)

Answer (score 5):

Its the first time I heard about Embox, but the tool to combine Embox with your code is obviously a [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) (so a cross `ld` from [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/), see [documentation of `ld`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/ld/index.html)). To understand more about linkers, read Levine's book [*Linkers and loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/)

The Embox produced by compiling Embox source code is probably a library (`libembox.a`), or a relocatable object file `embox.o` - possibly produced by `ld -r`).

The produced application image is probably a raw binary file (`.bin`) but it could be an ELF file if it is loaded by the GRUB loader.

I guess that the building process is quite similar to the Linux kernel build process.

BTW, I would imagine that developing on a Linux system could be simpler, since Linux uses the same kind of tools daily. So you might install Linux on your development laptop.

You need a cross-compiler (for your target platform) to compile your code to be combined with Embox.

Comment: Thanks @Basile Starynkevitch (+1) - I will be developing my app on either Windows or Ubuntu and flashing the final app (integrated with the Embox kernel) onto an ARM SAM3X8E microcontroller (so obviously Linux isn't an option). Do you know of any cross compilers for this platform? Do you know of the specific cross linker that would be compatible with Embox? Thanks again!

Comment: I guess that some recent GCC can be configured as a cross-compiler for your ARM. I don't know the details